# Why does bar graph get inverted when I use it in a infobox?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki-templates

The code for the page is

```
{{Infobox course
| course_code = PH31011
| course_name = Quantum Mechanics I
| department = [[Physics]]
| credits = 4
| ltp = {{Data bars
         | columns = 6 | Jan| Feb| Mar| Apr| May| Jun
         | blue|Berries|  65|  38|  72|  47|  20|  30  
        }}
}}

{{Data bars
| columns = 6 | Jan| Feb| Mar| Apr| May| Jun
| blue|Berries|  65|  38|  72|  47|  20|  30    
}}
```

Why does the graph display inverted bars when used in the infobox?

- [Both Graphs Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwmAs.png)
- [Demo page](https://test.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Arunpatro0/sandbox)

Comment: There is far too little information here to tell. How do those two templates (`infobox course` and `data bars`) look? If there is an extension involved in drawing te bars, which one, and what version?

Comment: Both the templates are standard ones as used in wikipedia.org
[Data Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Data_bars)
[Infobox Course](https://wiki.metakgp.org/w/Template:Infobox_course)

Comment: There does not seem to be a template called `Data bars`on that wiki? Also, you might want to mention that the Infobox is not a standard MediaWiki template, but a Lua script, probably copied from English Wikipedia, or some other Wikipedia edition, I guess.

Comment: I used both of them on test.wikipedia.org https://test.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Arunpatro0/sandbox and it errored. Could you suggest a way to mitigate the issue?

Comment: I suggest you add that link to the question, because it's not really possible to answer without it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CSS issue, and not really related to MediaWiki itself, but to a stylesheet created by the Wikimedia community. There is a css rule in [`MediaWiki:Common.css`](https://test.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css) (user created CSS loaded for all skins) on that wiki that looks like this:

```
.infobox th[scope=row], .infobox td {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

That rule overrides the vertical align of the bar. A quick and dirty fix would be to change `vertical-align: bottom;` to `vertical-align: bottom !important;` for each column in [`Template:Data_bars`](https://test.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Data_bars&action=edit).

As always, you risk messing up some other edge case if you do that on a production wiki, so you should probably raise the question on the [talk page](https://test.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template_talk:Data_bars&action=edit&redlink=1) first.

Comment: I changed the attributes of all the columns to `vertical-align: bottom !important`. It still doesn't work. The bars in the infobox are still on top.

Comment: Oh, I see, those rules were for tr's. You have changed it for the tr's, but need to set it for the td's! (Maybe you should simplify those templates a bit, if they are getting tricky to maintain?) Try using the developer tools in your browser, to see what rules are actually in place.

Comment: Here you are: https://test.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template%3AData_bars%2Fcolumn&type=revision&diff=274746&oldid=274742